# Hide Whatapp message preview on the front screen

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger

On new Samsung A3 2017, I want to hide Whatapp message preview on the front screen but keep the sound.  Is this no longer possible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the lock screen?

Comment: Or is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipXHz.jpg) what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check at **Settings >  Lock Screen & Security > Notification on Lock Screen**? There you can hide notification for specific apps.

[image: Screenshot taken from Samsung J5, Android 6.0.1]